# First and Last Datetime for year or year/month

Tags: php, datetime

I have an action which accepts a year and an optional month.  I need to query all articles written within that time, so I need the absolute first and last valid datetime for that timespan.

```
    $start = new \DateTime();
    $start->setDate((int) $year, (int) ($month ?: 1), 1);
    $start->setTime(0, 0);

    $end = clone $start;
    $end->add(new \DateInterval($month ? 'P1M' : 'P1Y'));
    $end->sub(new \DateInterval('PT1S'));
```

Is there a cleaner way to write this?

Comment: Why don't you query for all articles within that span of time, ORDER  BY the date the article was written ascending or descending (newest or oldest), and LIMIT 1 to only get the earliest or latest one. You probably don't need to find the datetimes separately from the desired rows.

Comment: And now for something completely different: instead of using the backslash in `\DateTime` all the time (I guess it's because you are using namespaces), you can add a `use DateTime` at the beginning of your file. Then the backslashes can be omitted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$start = mktime(0, 0, 0, $month ?: 1, 1, $year);
$end = mktime(23, 59, 59, $month ?: 12, $month ? date('t', $start) : 31, $year);
```

or

```
$start = new \DateTime("$year-" . ($month ?: 1) . '-1 00:00:00');
$end = new \DateTime("$year-" . ($month ?: 12) . '-' . ($month ? $start->format('t') : 31) . ' 23:59:59');
```

Not sure if you'd consider this cleaner, but it's shorter and does without relative calculations.

The *cleanest* and most understandable way to write this is probably:

```
if ($month) {
    $start = new \DateTime("$year-$month-1 00:00:00");
    $end   = new \DateTime("$year-$month-" . $start->format('t') . ' 23:59:59');
} else {
    $start = new \DateTime("$year-1-1 00:00:00");
    $end   = new \DateTime("$year-12-31 23:59:59");
}
```

You might not need to involve `DateTime` much at all here if you're going to use this as value for an SQL query.